# JsTree using AJAX call to get child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jsTree test</title>
<!-- 2 load the theme CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- 3 setup a container element -->
<div id="jstreee">
</div>


<!-- 4 include the jQuery library -->
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js">       </script>
<!-- 5 include the minified jstree source -->
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js">   </script>
<script>
var json_data = [];
$(function () {

$.get('url call here',function(data,status){

var dataL = JSON.parse(data);//console.log(dataL);
var obj = {};
obj["id"]=dataL["guid"];
obj["text"]=dataL["name"];
obj["parent"]="#";
console.log(obj);
json_data.push(obj);
$('#jstreee').jstree({ 'core' : {
'data' : json_data
} });
});
});

$('#jstreee').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
console.log("we are in the function");
console.log(data.selected);
var node_clicked = data.selected;
if (node_clicked == null) {
  node_clicked = "wiprohdmforg04july2016";
}
var url = "URL Call Here="+data.selected;
$.get(url,function(data,status){
var dataP = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(dataP.nodes);
var childlist = [];
console.log(dataP.nodes.length);
for(var i=0;i<dataP.nodes.length;i++){
var obj={};
obj["id"]=dataP.nodes[i].guid;
obj["text"]=dataP.nodes[i].name;
obj["parent"]=node_clicked;
//console.log("obj",obj);
var flag=0;
for(var j=0;j<json_data.length;j++){
if(obj["id"]===json_data[j]["id"]){
flag=1;
}
}
if(flag == 0){
json_data.push(obj);
}
console.log(json_data);
}
});
$('#jstreee').jstree(true).settings.core.data = json_data;
console.log("I reached here");
$('#jstreee').jstree(true).refresh(true);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to reload the tree with new data.(Json_data) but it is not populating,It is successfuly making an ajax call and checking for the duplication of the data and if data present it is not updating the json_data(new data).

But since I am using refresh(true it is forgetting the current state and again starts from the root level(1st level)).

I want the root child only to get updated instead of the complete tree.
Also I need to click twice on a tree value(as root level) to update the tree. 
But the data from url comes on 1st click only.

Example
--> Organization
------>Root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jsTree test</title>
<!-- 2 load the theme CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.m in.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- 3 setup a container element -->
<div id="jstreee">
</div>


<!-- 4 include the jQuery library -->
<script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<!-- 5 include the minified jstree source -->
<script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js">     </script>
<script>
var json_data = [];var ten= 0;

$(function () {

$.get('**root node url here**',function(data,status){

var dataL = JSON.parse(data);//console.log(dataL);
var obj = {};
obj["id"]=dataL["guid"];
obj["text"]=dataL["name"];
obj["parent"]="#";
console.log(obj);
json_data.push(obj);
$('#jstreee').jstree({
'core' : {
'data' : json_data
}
});
});
});
$('#jstreee').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
console.log("we are in the function");
var node_clicked = data.selected[0];
var url = "**your url here**"+node_clicked;
$.get(url,function(data,status){
console.log(data);
if (data.nodes !== null) {
var dataP = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(dataP.nodes);
var childlist = [];
console.log(dataP.nodes.length);
for(var i=0;i<dataP.nodes.length;i++){
var obj={};
obj["id"]=dataP.nodes[i].guid;
obj["text"]=dataP.nodes[i].name;
obj["parent"]=node_clicked;
//console.log("obj",obj);
var flag=0;
for(var j=0;j<json_data.length;j++){
if(obj["id"]===json_data[j]["id"]){
flag=1;
}
}
if(flag == 0){
json_data.push(obj);
ten = 0;
}
console.log(json_data);
}
refreshh();
}
});

function refreshh(){
$('#jstreee').jstree(true).settings.core.data = json_data;
console.log("I reached here");

if(ten == 0){
$('#jstreee').jstree(true).refresh(true);
ten = 1;
}
}
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

//// this code dynamically gets the dta from specific url and populates the jstree with new data, 
no problem with refresh now, 
succeessfully maintains the current state
ready to use just replace the urls...
2 urls,

### 1st the root node url and 2nd the url with the child node specific data

transforming data from url to desired format:
"
    for(var i=0;i

### "